# Incomplete png with ggarrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following problem. I have merged two plots with ggarrange and then finally saved them with ggsave. Unfortunately the .png files look a bit funny. The right and left part next to the legend is not filled in but does not exist. This leads unfortunately to the fact that the pictures in LaTeX e.g. do not look good. How can I adjust it so that also below next to the legend, the space becomes white.

My code:

```
(merge=ggarrange(gg1, gg2, ncol=2, common.legend = TRUE, legend="bottom"))
ggsave(uni4, filename = "file.png", path = "~/path", width = 24, height = 14, units = "cm", dpi=700)
```

[image: Pic]

UPDATE:
df = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oIlJPuIrYcqKOeqTdrXNzZubat-tV0J5q-tvQDqOnGk/edit?usp=sharing

```
g11 = ggplot() +
  geom_smooth(se = F, data = df, aes(x = sc, y = changes, color = factor(nr), group = factor(nr))) +
  scale_color_viridis(discrete = TRUE, option = "D")+
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") 

g21 = ggplot() +
  geom_smooth(se=F, data = df, aes(x = sc, y = changes, color = factor(nr), group = factor(nr))) +
  scale_color_viridis(discrete = TRUE, option = "D")+
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") 

(uni11=ggarrange(g11, g21, ncol=2, common.legend = TRUE, legend="bottom"))
ggsave(uni11, filename = "file.png", path = "~/path", width = 24, height = 8, units = "cm", dpi=700)
```

Comment: Hi Karl! Welcome to StackOverflow! Would you be able to share more of your code and data, so I'm able to reproduce your problem? Thanks!

Comment: @Mark See my updates!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible fix for your issue would be to manually set the background fill color using the `bg` argument of `ggsave`.

Using a minimal example based on `mtcars` let's first reproduce your issue:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

gg1 <- gg2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point()

merge <- ggarrange(gg1, gg2, ncol = 2, common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom")

ggsave(merge,
  filename = "file.png"
)
```

[image]

Now, to fix the issue with the "grey" or "black" space on the left and right of the legend we could export with `bg="white"`:

```
ggsave(merge,
  filename = "file1.png", bg = "white"
)
```

[image]